# DB2 : many-2-many join - converting json

Tags: python, join, db2, many-to-many

I have 2 tables (in DB2) which are actually relates as many-2-many example below

### Dataset-1

```
FP_ID|WS_ID|SC_ID|INC_NUM|INC_DESC
"FP1"|10101|"SC1"|1000001|"INC_11"
"FP1"|10101|"SC1"|1000002|"INC_12"
"FP1"|10101|"SC1"|1000003|"INC_13"
"FP1"|10101|"SC1"|1000004|"INC_14"
"FP2"|10101|"SC1"|1002002|"INC_12"
"FP2"|10101|"SC1"|1003003|"INC_13"
"FP1"|10201|"SC1"|1000004|"INC_14"
```

### Dataset-2

```
FP_ID|WS_ID|SC_ID|RSK_NUM|RSK_DESC
"FP1"|10101|"SC1"|1003001|"RSK_11"
"FP1"|10101|"SC1"|1003002|"RSK_12"
"FP1"|10101|"SC1"|1004004|"RSK_14"
"FP2"|10101|"SC1"|1005002|"RSK_12"
"FP2"|10101|"SC1"|1006003|"RSK_13"
"FP4"|10201|"SC1"|1007004|"RSK_14"
```

Now our joining condition b/w these two dataset is FP_ID, WS_ID and SC_ID. As these datasets are related to many-2-many, so it is generating many duplicate (not full row duplicate though). Actually these two dataset are having ~90K rows and these joins are generating billion records. I am thinking for a solution like below

### Dataset-1

```
FP_ID|WS_ID|SC_ID|INC_DTL
"FP1"|10101|"SC1"|{[{"INC_NUM":1000001,"INC_DESC":"INC_11"},{"INC_NUM":1000002,"INC_DESC":"INC_12"},{"INC_NUM":1000003,"INC_DESC":"INC_13"},{"INC_NUM":1000004,"INC_DESC":"INC_14"}]}
"FP2"|10101|"SC1"|{[{"INC_NUM":1003003,"INC_DESC":"INC_13"},{"INC_NUM":1002002,"INC_DESC":"INC_12"}]}
"FP1"|10201|"SC1"|{[{"INC_NUM":1000004,"INC_DESC":"INC_14"}]}
```

### Dataset-2

```
FP_ID|WS_ID|SC_ID|RSK_DTL
"FP1"|10101|"SC1"|{[{"RSK_NUM":1003001,"RSK_DESC":"RSK_11"},{"RSK_NUM":1003002,"RSK_DESC":"RSK_12"},{"RSK_NUM":1004004,"RSK_DESC":"RSK_14"}]}
"FP2"|10101|"SC1"|{[{"RSK_NUM":1005002,"RSK_DESC":"RSK_12"},{"RSK_NUM":1006003,"RSK_DESC":"RSK_13"}]}
"FP4"|10201|"SC1"|{[{"RSK_NUM":1007004,"RSK_DESC":"RSK_14"}]}
```

And then finally join these two datasets on FP_ID, WS_ID and SC_ID. But it looks like json_arrayagg is not supported with version 11 in Linux environment.

Can this be achieved by any other means like using python ?

Any hint towards solution will be very helpful.

Comment: You haven't provided the exact result set desired. What should we get, if, say, DS1 has 3 rows and DS2 has 2 rows for some `(FP_ID, WS_ID, SC_ID)` (or vice versa)? 1 row only with `INC_DTL` & `RSK_DTL` in the form of string representation of JSON document? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH DS1 (FP_ID, WS_ID, SC_ID, INC_NUM, INC_DESC) AS
(
VALUES
  ('FP1', 10101, 'SC1', 1000001, 'INC_11')
, ('FP1', 10101, 'SC1', 1000002, 'INC_12')
, ('FP1', 10101, 'SC1', 1000003, 'INC_13')
, ('FP1', 10101, 'SC1', 1000004, 'INC_14')
, ('FP2', 10101, 'SC1', 1002002, 'INC_12')
, ('FP2', 10101, 'SC1', 1003003, 'INC_13')
, ('FP1', 10201, 'SC1', 1000004, 'INC_14')
)
SELECT 
  FP_ID, WS_ID, SC_ID
,    '{[' 
  || LISTAGG ('{"INC_NUM":' || INC_NUM || ',"INC_DESC":"' || INC_DESC || '"}', ',')
  || ']}'
  AS JSON_COL
FROM DS1
GROUP BY FP_ID, WS_ID, SC_ID
```

| FP_ID | WS_ID | SC_ID | JSON_COL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FP1 | 10101 | SC1 | {[{"INC_NUM":1000001,"INC_DESC":"INC_11"},{"INC_NUM":1000004,"INC_DESC":"INC_14"},{"INC_NUM":1000003,"INC_DESC":"INC_13"},{"INC_NUM":1000002,"INC_DESC":"INC_12"}]} |
| FP1 | 10201 | SC1 | {[{"INC_NUM":1000004,"INC_DESC":"INC_14"}]} |
| FP2 | 10101 | SC1 | {[{"INC_NUM":1002002,"INC_DESC":"INC_12"},{"INC_NUM":1003003,"INC_DESC":"INC_13"}]} |

You may use `XMLAGG` to form larger `JSON_COL` values than `LISTAGG` supports instead.

Comment: I am having a long list of INC (over 10K +) and I have tried xmlserialize(xmlagg(xmltext(...)) as clob(5M)); but still there are data truncation. What max I can define ?

Comment: `CLOB (2G)` probably.

Comment: still with this I can see data truncation, even data truncation is there when I exporting to a file. I can see it can write upto max. 33195 characters

Comment: What' are the exact "export" command and tool you use?

Comment: export to <filename> of del <sql statement>

Comment: You must use the `modified by lobsinsepfile` clause to export each clob to a separate file (with reference to it in a base export file) and avoid data truncation.

Comment: lobsinsepfile is not working. lobsinfile working though. But it is really difficult to find which lob is for which row. the goal is upload in a MPP datavase where JSON object is supported directly. Not sure if these are separate files, how should it be uploaded

Comment: Correction: lobsinsepfile**s**. [LOB export considerations](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=data-lob-export-considerations).